# largeHeap to exceed Android machine-specific max heap size

Tags: android, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm currently building an Android project that I believe will use quite a lot of RAM, much more than the default max heap size set by devices.

The app will be the only one that runs on our Android machines (they're single-purpose), so I'm not worried about slowing down other processes. I want all the resources possible to go to this one program.

I know that I can use

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

to give myself more room. However, in another post, a commenter suggested that this setting does not override the machine-specific max heap size. Is this true? And if so, is there another way to exceed this limit?

As an aside, I saw some posts that show how to do this natively. Unfortunately, I'm a mere Java programmer and so I have to work within the constraints of Dalvik.

Comment: Do you have a link to the other post in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This option is only for Honeycomp tablets ATM.For API levels below Honeycomp the only thing you can do is increase the heap size of all applications (Rooted phone) I haven't actually used is but check this [video](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=_CruQY55HOk) from Google IO at 06:00. It said that expands the heap size. So probably he is correct and not the commenter you mentioned :D